# How to expand mat-expansion-panel for specific id only from the fetch table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-6

I am developing a list of items. Each item is fetched and placed inside the mat-expansion-panel using the loop inside my html file.

What I am trying to do is: If the id of some item is passed into the URL (say: example.com/items/id) then the expansion panel of that id 
 will expand only and if that item is not found then it will look the database for that item and push it inside the current item list and this same process will again call and this time that item will be found and gets expanded.

My current approach is similar to this logic.

My .HTML file:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items" [expanded]="">
        // Content 
    </mat-expansion-pane>
</mat-accordion>
```

My Component.ts file:

```
expandItem(id: string) {

   this.getAllItems(); // calling list of all items and saving it into 'items' variable.

    for (const item of this.items) {
        if (item.id === id) {
             console.log('Found item into the list');
            // expand that expansion panel somehow -_-'
        } else {
            console.log('not found in the list');

            // Now fetch that item from Database.
            this.FunctionService.getItem(id).subscribe((data: {}) => {
                this.item = data;
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

            if (this.item) {
               // if found then push this item inside the list and call this function again so that this time item will be found and gets expanded.
                this.items.push(this.item);
                this.expandFunction(id);
            }
        }
    }
}



ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params['id']) {
            this.expandItem(params['id']); // call function which contains the expand panel code
        } else {
            this.getAllItems(); // otherwise call all items
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just copy your if logic to the template?

```
<mat-accordion>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="item.id === paramId" (click)="expandItem(item.id)">
            // Content 
        </mat-expansion-pane>
    </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>
```

TS:

```
paramId: string;
expandItem(id: string) {
    this.paramId = id;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: But what if the item is not present on the list of fetch records. As records can be 100 0 and I am fetching 30 records at once.

Comment: @darky Sorry, I didn't mean move the if/else logic completely to the template. Essentially, you can have the id check in the template and the TS can stay intact with the addition of assigning the id to a variable.